# Why should I avoid having differents filesystem for / and /home?

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem

As stated [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemsExplained)

> it's ok to have two partitions on for Linux system files and another for home files in the same disk but they should be both the same filesystem.

Now, on one of my machine I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS partitioned in this way:

- 10GB / ext4
- 482GB /home XFS

And I'm not experiencing issues at all.
In fact, it seems to be running smoother than a "full" ext4 partitioning scheme.
So, what's the deal?
Can someone kindly shine a light on this for me?
Thank you.

Comment: Well, you probably wouldn't want to store your data in, for example, and NTFS partition since the permissions wouldn't work.

Comment: I'll say only the writer knows...(a.k.a. non-sense?)

Comment: FWIW, it's a wiki...

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes, I agree with you, but as far as I know XFS is compatibile with linux permission.

Comment: It is a good choice to use `ext4` for `/` and `XFS` for `/home`.

Comment: another thing: when foreign filesystems break you need the operating system for that filesystem to be 100% sure you fix it at is should be fixed. Using another OS tools is never 100% sure to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think @AndroidDev is right, it's just about unix file permissions that can't be saved in FAT{12,16,32}, or exFAT and hardly in NTFS. The author clearly had the standard example of a Windows user switching to Ubuntu in mind, see the last section of the wiki page. Btw, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947787/is-there-an-english-ubuntu-wiki) for a discussion about the quality of your linked wiki.

**tl;dr**: Mixing file system in your installation should be no problem as long as they are all suitable for Linux, i. e. support file system permissions as well as symbolic links. In general this means every filesystem is fine except FAT and NTFS.

([source (German)](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Dateisystem/#Grundlegende-Merkmale))

Comment: I didn't know about the wiki, thank you. BTW I think I can use any combination of linux supported FS then, is it right?

Comment: @ClaudioCortese you can use any filesystem that is POSIX compliant.

Comment: @ClaudioCortese … as well as any combination of them, yes.