# How to install Mars [Radeon HD 8730M] drivers ? Is It supported?

Tags: drivers, radeon, vmware

I bought Dell Inspiron 15r -5521 with i7-750GB HDD-8GB Ram.

```
abutareq@P-Box:~$ sudo lshw -businfo | grep -i display
pci@0000:01:00.0              display        Mars [Radeon HD 8730M]
pci@0000:00:02.0              display        3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
```

Steam keeps telling me when I change the display that I have only 250 MB video memory.

I removed windows and installed Ubuntu 13.10 because I want to use windows on Vmware and I read about enabling 3d in VM but my device does not support 3d, that's what Vmware says.

Comment: if you go to settings manager -> additional drivers, what graphic drivers do you see?

Comment: settings manager -> additional drivers .. I chose the second once but my screen goes black after reboot and I fix by reading some answers .. Screen Shot-> http://www2.0zz0.com/2014/02/09/19/408993230.png

Answer (score 0):

For ways to check compatibility of a given graphics card with Ubuntu see this question: [At Present Which is the best choice for a Ubuntu graphics card, AMD or nVidia?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90671/at-present-which-is-the-best-choice-for-a-ubuntu-graphics-card-amd-or-nvidia/413289#413289).

In your case, there [doesn't seem to be any official certification](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/search/?query=8730) for Radeon HD 8730M (which doesn't necessarily mean that it's not at all supported).

There is at least [one report](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?85388-Catalyst-13-11-Beta-Brings-New-GPU-Support-To-Linux/page2) that the latest version of the proprietary `AMD Catalyst` drivers (version `13.12`) support your card. You can download them from [AMD Graphics Drivers and Software](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download). See somewhat related discussion: [AMD Radeon HD 8670D: Gallium3D vs. Catalyst](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amd_gallium3d_hd8670d&num=1).

See also:

- [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

Comment: Will I think that mean the graphic driver I am using now is not supported yet. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it could be supported. See edit.