# black screen when setting 20-radeon.conf

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, tearing

I have a dell Inspiron 15R 5521 with radeon 8730M / intel 4000 dual gpu configuration running Ubuntu 16.04 running kernel 4.8.1.I have been facing horrible screen tearing when using my discrete GPU using the `DRI_PRIME=1` command.

I tried the solution given in [this](https://cubethethird.wordpress.com/2016/06/14/eliminate-screen-tearing-with-amd-gpu-on-ubuntu/) link here. However when is create this config file, I get a black screen on bootup or whenever lightDM restarts with the error

> ```
> radeon vce init error(-110)
> ```

I remove that file the system back to boot without error, however is there any other solution to handle screen tearing while using my radeon gpu?

**--EDIT--**
i added the output of the file generated by the code

```
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Inspiron 5521
 ==
 *-display UNCLAIMED
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Mars [Radeon HD 8730M]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:c0000000-c003ffff   ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c0040000-c005ffff
*-display UNCLAIMED
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:c1000000-c13fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff       ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
==
```

as for the xorg.conf
it gave the output 
cat: /etc/X11/xorg.conf : No such file or directory
is that normal ?

**-----EDIT-2----**

So i tried to set up xorg.conf in an attempt to fix the issue using `X -configure` but i get the following error

`Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.`

on googling the issue i found a lot of solutions that applied to different cases like dual monitor setups and all but none that fit my case.

[here](http://pastebin.com/j85tVbu3) is the full log file describing my issue.
Really appreciate if somebody could help me with this

Comment: To get back to normal, on boot press shift key, choose recovery, check for free space then drop to shell and remove that file.

Comment: already did that . System works as before  but the screen tearing stays

Comment: I'm not experienced with this,  but adding more info to the question may attract users faced same issue. Could you [edit] the question and add the contents of `~/Desktop/ubuntu-graphic-info.txt` generated by `sudo sh -c "lsb_release -sd; dmidecode -s system-product-name; echo ==; lshw -c display; echo ==; xrandr --verbose; cat /etx/X11/xorg.conf" | tee ~/Desktop/ubuntu-graphic-info.txt`

Comment: added the info from the command

Comment: Same case, no solution, no driver support https://askubuntu.com/questions/418454/how-to-install-mars-radeon-hd-8730m-drivers-is-it-supported & this one too from Ubuntu forum https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2234328

Comment: Have you tried the proprietary driver https://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86_64 ? I'm not sure about results either. Read how to uninstall it first, at least you can fix system, if it does break the GUI boot.

Comment: The support for proprietary drivers was drawn in 16.04, They were replaced by these opensource drivers