# Ubuntu on ARM platform PC

Tags: arm

I have read that Ubuntu runs on ARM computers, but where are they then? I have searched and searched, but have found no pc maker that has ARM desktop computers, can some one please help me? I know Nvidia has project denver that makes the ARM processor availatble for the desktop, but I have not found a desktop with it yet

Ole

Comment: You can find all the ARM/Ubuntu Information here --- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM

Comment: [from my previous question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/434393/installing-ubuntu-on-android-netbooks) it seems that ubuntu killed arm releases, if that's true, I'd go for arch or debian http://www.raspbian.org

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's close to a PC/Laptop is the AC100: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/TEGRA/AC100

Answer (score 1):

Chromebook series have some ARM laptops. Unfortunately, it has no real advantage against x86 in laptops under Linux, except of being able to run Android apps after serious fiddling. ARM laptops have no longer battery life because screen and video card consume much more power than CPU.